# Log integration

Tags: integration

> What is the value of $$\frac{1}{\pi^{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln
> x)^{2}}{\sqrt{x}(1-x)^{2}} d x$$

I tried with by parts.But not able to 
Proceed further. Tried with put $x=\sin^2\theta$

Comment: I tried with your trigo part, but nothing is happening

Comment: I'm pretty sure that diverges at $0$.

Comment: Can we integrate it?

Comment: $x=\sin^2\theta$ is not a valid substitution because $x\in(0,\infty)$ but $\sin^2\theta$ can never go that far.

Comment: @B.Goddard That is incorrect. The singularity at $0$ is an integrable one, so it converges.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty (...)=\int_0^1 (...)+\int_1^\infty (...)$ then perform the change of variable $y=1/x$ in the second integral.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a result of 2.

Comment: @FDP can u give soln

Comment: You just need to let $x\to t^2$ to arrive at the duplicated integral.